# Why was Henry Wilcox released from prison in Covert Affairs?

Tags: plot-explanation, covert-affairs

I am unclear as to how the failed drone strike in the episode S03E14 "Scary Monsters (and Super Creeps)" caused Henry Wilcox to be released from his prison sentence for treason. Why was he released?